# Errors when running monerod on ubuntu -- ERROR cn src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:1127

Tags: monerod, error-log

I'm getting the below error on ubuntu 14.04 when running monerd in the command line. How to resolve this?

```
2017-09-16 21:53:02.700 [P2P3]  ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:662 Exception at [core::handle_incoming_txs()], what=Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2017-09-16 21:53:02.710 [P2P3]  WARN    blockchain.db.lmdb  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:72   DB error attempting to fetch block index from hashMDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2017-09-16 21:53:02.722 [P2P3]  ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:1127    Exception at [core::handle_incoming_block()], what=DB error attempting to fetch block index from hashMDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2017-09-16 21:53:02.729 [P2P3]  ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:662 Exception at [core::handle_incoming_txs()], what=Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2017-09-16 21:53:02.734 [P2P3]  WARN    blockchain.db.lmdb  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:72   DB error attempting to fetch block index from hashMDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2017-09-16 21:53:02.752 [P2P3]  ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:1127    Exception at [core::handle_incoming_block()], what=DB error attempting to fetch block index from hashMDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2017-09-16 21:53:02.757 [P2P3]  ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:662 Exception at [core::handle_incoming_txs()], what=Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2017-09-16 21:53:02.766 [P2P3]  WARN    blockchain.db.lmdb  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:72   DB error attempting to fetch block index from hashMDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2017-09-16 21:53:02.778 [P2P3]  ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:1127    Exception at [core::handle_incoming_block()], what=DB error attempting to fetch block index from hashMDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2017-09-16 21:53:02.792 [P2P3]  ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:662 Exception at [core::handle_incoming_txs()], what=Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2017-09-16 21:53:02.792 [P2P3]  WARN    blockchain.db.lmdb  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:72   DB error attempting to fetch block index from hashMDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2017-09-16 21:53:02.796 [P2P3]  ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:1127    Exception at [core::handle_incoming_block()], what=DB error attempting to fetch block index from hashMDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2017-09-16 21:53:02.823 [P2P3]  ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:662 Exception at [core::handle_incoming_txs()], what=Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2017-09-16 21:53:02.823 [P2P3]  WARN    blockchain.db.lmdb  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:72   DB error attempting to fetch block index from hashMDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2017-09-16 21:53:02.827 [P2P3]  ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:1127    Exception at [core::handle_incoming_block()], what=DB error attempting to fetch block index from hashMDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2017-09
```

Comment: Is this with 0.10.3.1 or 0.11.0.0 ? This was supposed to be fixed in 0.11.0.0 (though this is usually a secondary error, with the real error being earlier).